How to evaluate $\int\limits^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{\cos\left(u\right) - r}{\left(1 + r^{2} - 2r \cos\left(u\right)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} du$
I am looking for a practical solution for $0<r<1$
$$\int\limits^{2\pi}_{0} \frac{\cos\left(u\right) - r}{\left(1 + r^{2} - 2r \cos\left(u\right)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}} du$$
My attempt:
$y = 1 + r^2 - 2r \cos(u)$
$du=\frac{dy}{2r\sin(u)}$ with this integral becomes
$$\frac{1}{2r}\int\limits^{(r-1)^2}_{(r-1)^2}\frac{\cos(u) - r}{y^{3/2}\sin(u)}dy=0$$ but WolframAlpha finds diffrently (for example it finds $0.003141596...$ for $r=0.001$). I am not knowledgeable in Complex Analysis or Elliptic Integrals, so an elementary solution would be greatly appreciated, if possible. Thank you in advance.

There is no elementary solution here. You will need elliptic integrals to express the final result, and there’s no getting around it.

Note that $\frac{\cos(u)-r}{{(1+r^2-2r\cos(u))}^{3/2}}=\frac{d}{dr}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+r^2-2r\cos(u)}}$.

Does this integral come from a double integral in polar coordinates, by any chance? If so, it's possible the original integral might be in fact be elementary.

@user170231 If that is the case, I have no knowledge of it. It was presented to me in this form.

OK. I only ask because I came across a very similar double integral the other day, one component of which evaluates to an elliptic integral, despite the overall double integral having a simple value.

Let $\rho=\dfrac{2\sqrt r}{1+r}$. By $(1)$ symmetry and $(2)$ substitution of $u\to\dfrac{\pi-u}2$, we have
$$\begin{align*}
I(r) &= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos u - r}{\left(1+r^2-2r\cos u\right)^{3/2}} \, du \\
&\stackrel{(1)}= \frac2{\left(1+r^2\right)^{3/2}} \int_0^\pi \frac{\cos u-r}{\left(1-\frac{\rho^2}2\cos u\right)^{3/2}} \, du \\
&\stackrel{(2)}= -\frac4{\left(1+r^2\right)^{3/2}} \int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{\cos(2u)+r}{\left(1+\frac{\rho^2}2\cos(2u)\right)^{3/2}} \, du \\
&= \frac8{(1+r)^3}\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\frac{\sin^2u}{\left(1-\rho^2\sin^2u\right)^{3/2}} \, du-\frac4{(1+r)^2}\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\frac{du}{\left(1-\rho^2\sin^2u\right)^{3/2}} \\
&\!\!\!\stackrel{(3),(4)}= \frac8{(1-r)^2(1+r)} \underbrace{\int_0^\tfrac\pi2 \frac{1-\sin^2u}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2\sin^2u}} \, du}_{I_1} -\frac4{(1-r)^2}\underbrace{\int_0^\tfrac\pi2\sqrt{1-\rho^2\sin^2u}\,du}_{I_2}
\end{align*}$$
The reductions to $I_1$ and $I_2$ respectively follow from $(3)$ and $(4)$. $I_1$ can be further broken down into a linear combination of $E(\rho)$ and $K(\rho)$.
We ultimately find that
$$I(r)=\frac2{r(1-r)}E\left(\frac{2\sqrt r}{1+r}\right)-\frac2{r(1+r)}K\left(\frac{2\sqrt r}{1+r}\right)$$
or equivalently, applying identities listed here,
$$\begin{align*}
K(k)&\stackrel{(127)}=\frac1{1+k}K\left(\frac{2\sqrt k}{1+k}\right) \\
E(k)&\stackrel{(139)}=\left(1+\sqrt{1-k^2}\right)E\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-k^2}}{1+\sqrt{1-k^2}}\right)-\sqrt{1-k^2}K(k)
\end{align*}$$
$$\implies I(r) = \frac4{r\left(1-r^2\right)} E(r) - \frac4r K(r)$$

You can try in the following lines:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(u)-r}{(1+r^2-2r\cos(u))^{\frac{3}{2}}}du=\frac{1}{2r}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2r\cos(u)-2r^2-1+1}{(1+r^2-2r\cos(u))^{\frac{3}{2}}}du$$
then the right hand side is just evaluating
$$\frac{1}{2r}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-r^2}{(1+r^2-2r\cos(u))^{\frac{3}{2}}}du-\frac{1}{2r}\int_0^{2\pi}(1+r^2-2r\cos(u))^{-\frac{1}{2}}du$$
Now substitute $y=(1+r^2-2r\cos(u))^{\frac{1}{2}}$. This will yield
$$\frac{dy}{r\sin(u)}=(1+r^2-2r\cos(u))^{-\frac{1}{2}}du$$
Replace the value of $r\sin(u)$ from the substitution equation in terms of $y$ and change the limits of the integration accordingly. I think you will be good to go.

Too long for comments.
@user170231 gave the exact solution.
If, by practical, you mean that you wish a shortcut method for the numerical evaluation of
$$I(r)= \frac4{r\left(1-r^2\right)} E(r) - \frac4r K(r)$$ you could build the  series expansion around $r=0$ and have
$$I(r)=\frac{\pi r}{ \left(1-r^2\right)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n}{b_n}   r^{2n}  $$ where the $b_n$ correspond to sequence $A278145$ in $OEIS$ and the first $a_n$ are
$$\{1,1,3,25,245,1323,7623,184041,4601025,29548805,193947611,2591845347,\cdots
  \}$$
The summation will converge quite fast since, if $$c_n= \frac {a_n}{b_n}\qquad \implies \qquad \frac {c_{n+1}}{c_n} \sim 1-\frac 2 n$$
